# "*** No rule to make target `Makevars', needed by `Makefile'. Stop." while installing Invenio

Tags: software-installation, error-handling, execute-command

When I execute the command `make` to install invenio
this error appears:

```
make all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/src/invenio'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/src/invenio/po'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `Makevars', needed by `Makefile'. Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/src/invenio/po'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/src/invenio'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed it following this [guide](http://invenio-software.org/wiki/Installation/InvenioOnDebian).
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Did the other steps from the guide work without error?

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrased from the official installation instructions:

The pre-requisites can be installed by:

```
sudo aptitude install python-dev apache2-mpm-prefork \
    mysql-server mysql-client python-mysqldb \
    python-4suite-xml python-simplejson python-xml \
    python-libxml2 python-libxslt1 gnuplot poppler-utils \
    gs-common antiword catdoc wv html2text ppthtml xlhtml \
    clisp gettext libapache2-mod-wsgi unzip python-numpy \
    python-rdflib python-gnuplot python-magic pdftk \
    html2text giflib-tools pstotext make sudo
sudo aptitude install python-psyco sbcl cmucl \
    pylint pychecker pyflakes python-profiler python-epydoc \
    libapache2-mod-xsendfile
sudo aptitude install postfix
```

Install Invenio as usual:

```
cd ~/src
git clone http://invenio-software.org/repo/invenio
cd invenio
sudo aptitude install automake1.9 autoconf
aclocal-1.9
automake-1.9 -a
autoconf
./configure
make
make install
make install-mathjax-plugin
make install-jquery-plugins
make install-ckeditor-plugin
```

Note: make install will advise you to create symbolic links from the installation directory of invenios python-libs to the systemwide libs, e.g.

```
ln -s /opt/invenio/lib/python/invenio /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/invenio
ln -s /opt/invenio/lib/python/invenio /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/invenio
```

3) Load demo data:

```
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /opt/invenio
sudo -u www-data emacs /opt/invenio/etc/invenio-local.conf
sudo -u www-data /opt/invenio/bin/inveniocfg --update-all
sudo -u www-data /opt/invenio/bin/inveniocfg --create-tables
sudo -u www-data /opt/invenio/bin/inveniocfg --load-webstat-conf
sudo -u www-data /opt/invenio/bin/inveniocfg --create-demo-site
sudo -u www-data /opt/invenio/bin/inveniocfg --load-demo-records
```

Note: --create-tables will advise you how to set up your MySQL database and permissions in case this is not already done.

Configure Apache virtual hosts:

```
## generate Apache vhost snippets:
sudo -u www-data /opt/invenio/bin/inveniocfg --create-apache-conf

## make SSL certificate:
sudo aptitude install ssl-cert
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
sudo /usr/sbin/make-ssl-cert /usr/share/ssl-cert/ssleay.cnf \
       /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem

## add Invenio web sites:
sudo ln -s /opt/invenio/etc/apache/invenio-apache-vhost.conf \
             /etc/apache2/sites-available/invenio
sudo ln -s /opt/invenio/etc/apache/invenio-apache-vhost-ssl.conf \
             /etc/apache2/sites-available/invenio-ssl

## disable Debian's default web site:
sudo /usr/sbin/a2dissite default

## enable Invenio web sites:
sudo /usr/sbin/a2ensite invenio
sudo /usr/sbin/a2ensite invenio-ssl

## enable SSL module:
sudo /usr/sbin/a2enmod ssl

## if you are using xsendfile module, enable it too:
sudo /usr/sbin/a2enmod xsendfile

## restart Apache:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Done. Enjoy your Invenio instance.